# How to create a child or value without key?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So this is my TypeScript code to automatically add time of data creation:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const onAccCreate = functions.database
.ref('/Agent/{AgentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
 //const AgentID = context.params.AgentID
    console.log('New User ${AgentID} has joined.')

    const timeCreated = Date.now()
    return snapshot.ref.push({"Time": timeCreated})
})
```

This is my output:

[image]

I want TIME to be direct child of "Automation".
I don't want that key in between.
What should I do?
I have uploaded the code to firebase function to do so.

And also why is that `${AgentID}` looking as normal test in console.log 
I want that value of AgentID to be there.

Comment: Please use proper Tag. Do you want code in Java or Kotlin ?

Comment: @Ashish Thats Typescript... app is made in Java, but the above script is typescript

Comment: Please post code of typescript which you used to create agent

Comment: I have done that through `databaseRef.child("Agent);` and so on

Comment: only adding time is being done through the typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question use update then it will work for your requirement.

```
snapshot.ref.update({"Time": timeCreated})
```

For the second question

Add backticks instead of quotes and uncomment the `AgentID` variable

Answer (score 0):

The node you want gone is created by the fact that you call `push()`. If you don't want to generate a new child node with a unique ID, call `set` instead:

```
snapshot.ref.set({"Time": timeCreated})
```

Comment: It is working BUT another huge problem arises. It DELETES all other child nodes of "Automation" .. only Time remains the node then help